cronjob running python script to log - timestamp incorrect
I have a nightly cronjob that runs a python script.  The job sends all of the outputs to a log wherein each line is timestamped to the microsecond.
Part of that script includes a loop with a 5-second pause between each iteration.  When I was troubleshooting some issues, I noticed that the cronjob timestamp did not reflect that 5-second pause.  So I then included some python code to print its own timestamp, and the 5-second pause is clearly shown.
So, my question is:
Is my timestamp format correct for the cronjob log?
If so - why is the 5-second pause not showing?
If not - what is the correct format?
cronjob:
python myscript.py | ts '[\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%.S]' >> cronjob.log 2>&1
output:
[2024-09-05 00:23:24.226220]    > Doing something (time = 2024-09-05 00:22:19.738), attempt #1...
[2024-09-05 00:23:24.226234]    > Doing something (time = 2024-09-05 00:22:24.746), attempt #2...
[2024-09-05 00:23:24.226248]    > Doing something (time = 2024-09-05 00:22:29.753), attempt #3...
[2024-09-05 00:23:24.226261]    > Doing something (time = 2024-09-05 00:22:34.760), attempt #4...
[2024-09-05 00:23:24.226275]    > Doing something (time = 2024-09-05 00:22:39.769), attempt #5...

I'm less concerned about the timestamps lining up (cronjob vs. python), but maybe that's a clue?!
Note: If I run >ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%.S]' from the command line, the timestamp works as expected.

Do you have the TZ environment set in your interactive shell? cron is running in the system's timezone, which may be different.

I don't know about the timezone, but would that really affect the seconds portion of this?  Seems like it would just be off by X hours.

Sorry, I commented too quickly. Whenever someone says "time incorrect" I assume they mean it's off by hours, not seconds.

It seems that the problem is none of cron's business.
I've tried with the following code
import time
from datetime import datetime
for i in range(0,5):
    print(datetime.now())
    time.sleep(1)

When I execute it with python test.py everything works fine. But when I try to redirect to tc with pipe. Your problem occurs.
The problem is due to buffer, it seems that buffer in pipe is block buffer.
So, for your question, the solution is flushing the stdout
import time
from datetime import datetime
for i in range(0,5):
    print(datetime.now(), flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)

or
import time
import sys
from datetime import datetime
for i in range(0,5):
    print(datetime.now())
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)

here are some pipe buffer related answers:
How to turn off stdout buffering in a pipe?
Force line-buffering of stdout in a pipeline
How big is the pipe buffer?

Buffering affects when the output actually gets sent, but it shouldn't affect the contents of the output.

This is really interesting.  I'm very unfamiliar with unix/linux so don't really know how that all works.  I should have posted my python code and that it is Python 2.7 (don't tell anyone).  Anyway, I'll give it a go now and report back, thanks.

This was the fix, thank you!

@Barmar - but "when the output actually gets sent" is exactly the problem.  And now that I look at it, the stdout timestamps are all after the python system time because it dumped a ton of output basically all at the same time... after the code was run.

I really need to read questions completely.

I thought they were talking about the timestamps in the messages they're printing, not a receiver adding a timestamp.
